# EFBootstrapper Ninject to Unity EFBootStrapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container, ninject

I am following one of the example from http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/entity-framework-code-first-bootstrapping

In that post Kazi used Ninject but in my case I choose Unity as my IOC container.

I am finding difficuty in translating the following niject module code in to Unity code. All the help will be apreciated.

```
public class DataAccessModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<DataContextFactory>()
            .ToMethod(c => new DataContextFactory("DefaultConnection"))
            .InRequestScope();

        Bind<DataContext>()
            .ToMethod(c => c.Kernel.Get<DataContextFactory>().GetContext());

        Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
        Bind<UnitOfWork>().ToSelf();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for the registration

```
public class DataAccessModule : UnityContainerExtension
{
  protected override void Initialize()
  {
    this.Container.RegisterType<DataContextFactory>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager(), 
      new InjectionFactory(c => new DataContextFactory("DefaultConnection")));
    this.Container.RegisterType<DataContext>(
      new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<DataContextFactory>().GetContext()));
    this.Container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
  }
}
```

A sample for the `HttpContextLifetimeManager`can be found [here](http://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/242485).

You need to add the `DataAccessModule` to your container in your composition root.

```
container.AddNewExtension<DataAccessModule>();
```

Comment: Super Seb. It's working fantabulous. But I got the HttpContextLifetimeManager from the following location.http://code.google.com/p/ironframework/source/browse/trunk/IronFramework/Utility/EntLib/IoC/HttpContextLifetimeManager.cs?spec=svn61&r=61 and changed the just one line like this .RegisterType<DataContextFactory>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<DataContextFactory>(), new InjectionFactory(c => new DataContextFactory("DefaultConnection")))        is that alright?

Comment: @Naren There's a couple of implementations for an `HttpContext`-backed `LifetimeManager` out there. Just pick the one that fits your needs.